# pytest is not accepting a custom argument value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I'm trying to run pytest with a custom input argument "--trustkey_jks".

Running like this:

```
sh-4.2$ pytest -m test_e2e.py --trustkey_jks somekey
ERROR: usage: py.test [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
py.test: error: argument --trustkey_jks: expected one argument
```

Also tried like this:

```
sh-4.2$ py.test --trustkey_jks somekey test_e2e.py
ERROR: usage: py.test [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
py.test: error: argument --trustkey_jks: expected one argument
```

Can omit a file name to let pytest to collect any tests:

```
sh-4.2$ py.test --trustkey_jks somekey
ERROR: usage: py.test [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
py.test: error: argument --trustkey_jks: expected one argument
```

My conftest.py (same level as tests_e2e.py):

```
# conftest.py
def pytest_addoption(parser):
         parser.addoption("--trustkey_jks", action="store")

@pytest.fixture()
def trustkey_jks(request):
    return request.config.getoption("--trustkey_jks")
```

As far as i understand, pytest fails at parsing input arguments.
Appreciate any help.

NOTE: the above is happening inside an Openshift POD, not sure if it matters.

Comment: Did you try `=`?

Comment: Yes, i did try '=' and using quotes like --trustkey_jks=somekey or --trustkey_jks="somekey"

Comment: Usage says options go before `file_or_dir` argument, which you don't seem to have provided: `usage: py.test [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]`

Comment: I edited the question to show I also tried to place options before a file. And also '-m' doesn't make any difference in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to reproduce your issue at my end and also found the root-cause.The issue is the **conftest.py** of pytest functionality.

You need to add all the parser.addoption in your conftest.py as it would be loaded by default from conftest by pytest. And If you want to add command line parameters in your python file(without creating conftest.py), use following snippet:-

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--trustkey_jks", action="store_true")
```

Also, refer the conftest.py features:- https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/simple.html.